# (Excel VBA) How to maintain a cell value from an instant of a changing variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a drop down menu that allows my user to pick from a set, and I am then referencing that set in a button started macro to collect information to complete a table. Is there a way that I can lock a cell to the value from the drop down at the instant that the macro is run only. i.e. I don't want the values for the lines that I've already created with the macro to be effected when the drop down options are changed.

Comment: You can but sounds like a convoluted way of doing something/better to do it another way?

Comment: Can you post that macro? With your macro, why not add some logic that could end with the value being pasted as a value, not formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a value in a cell (let's use `A1`, with the value "10").  When you run a macro, you want this value to not change.

Just add something like this to the start of your macro:

```
Dim constCell as Range, constVal as String
Set constCell = Range("A1")
constVal = constCell.Value

... 
' Put your other macro stuff here
...

' And just before the `End Sub`, put the value back inplace:
constCell.Value = constVal 'this resets the cell to the original value, after your other macro stuff has run.
```